# how to create persistent random numbers &letters in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Below is link for example sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-D29csRGAAZl_h7fyMwLJ6am0FpZAtCZ5r0XlmQVqo/edit?usp=sharing.  This is a live spreadsheet, which can't be pasted in this question, but here's a screenshot of it's current state:

[image]

In column A, there will be numbers from 1- continued

In column C, there will be random lower case and upper case letters and numbers, totaling 11 characters.

Is there way to lock columns A&C so they can't be edited or refreshed once the values have been entered or calculated?

Comment: When you say "edited", that is clear for column A.  In column C are you really talking about preventing the values from being refreshed by the system and changed in the process?

Comment: i want the values to stay the same once they are generated example EWddC6dPjo4 so once i refresh i want the value to be EWddC6dPjo4 no changes and the column A&C i don't want anything to be change no values changed manually in other words like if i was to click on it i don't want it to change so it needs to be locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the random value formulas from updating, you need to overwrite them with their values. To do this, copy the range and `Paste Special` > `Values` back into the same range. This will remove the formulas and leave only the values.

If you want to disable manual editing (e.g., accidental deletion or keyboard input), you'll need to lock the range with the random values and protect the sheet. To do this, follow these steps:

1. On the worksheet, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. This will select all the cells on the sheet. Right click on the selection, and choose `Format Cells...`.
2. In the dialog that pops up, go to the `Protection` tab. Uncheck the `Locked` checkbox and click OK.
3. Now select the range of values you want to protect. Right click the selection and choose `Format Cells...`. Go to the `Protection` tab in the dialog that pops up and check the `Locked` checkbox. Click OK.
4. Finally, go to the `Review` ribbon and click `Protect Sheet`. In the dialog, you can choose what users can do to the sheet. I suggest checking every box. You may set a password as well, but it is not necessary. Once you protect the sheet, no changes can be made to the locked values unless you unprotect the sheet first.

Comment: i tried using it on google sheets but every time i refresh its different numbers I'm using the following formula if you can suggested me better way it will be really helpful and i want the forumula to apply to entire column =CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))&RANDBETWEEN(10,99)

Comment: @Sim - your question has Excel tags but your example is in Google.  Google is a different beast.  If you want to do this in Excel, this answer explains how.  If you need to do it in Google, the answer will be completely different.  You should modify the question to clarify which platform you need an answer for.

Comment: @fixer1234 understood as far as the formula goes the only way to create random numbers and letters are through =char right? or is there another way

Comment: With Excel, there are usually multiple ways to do anything.  Off the top of my head, if you want another approach to creating the strings, you could create a list of the upper/lower case characters and numbers and then use RANDBETWEEN to select from the list.  The list could be in a column and you could use a function like INDEX to select based on the RANDBETWEEN value.  Concatenate as many as you need to create the string.

Comment: so if i use MS Excel what is the best way to do it could you provide me the full formula thanks

Comment: i have MS excel 2013

Comment: i found another solution copy and paste the code :) thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to record the results of the random generation of words or numbers. I have this but the problem is if the number is already been it does not register it.
I need a fix for this:
Go to excel File options --> formulas, then enable interative calculations.
Next, in b1 = random number/letter output,
In A1 the formula:
=IF(C1=1,IF(A1="",B1,A1),"")
Then in A2 this formula:
=IF(AND($C$1=1,A1<>"",A1<>$B$1),IF(A2="",$B$1,A2),"")
And drag down.
Then, to get it all started, type "1" in c1. Each time you press f9, a new random number will appear and will be recorded in column A. To reset, just delete the 1 at C1.
For a different version, have this in A2 and drag down:
=IF(AND($C$1=1,A1<>0,A1<>$B$1),IF(A2=0,$B$1,A2),A2)